# .each function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

The code below is supposed to give a class to every day in a calendar(FullCalendar) in which i have planned a vacation. The dateArray shown is a string built by php, converted to an array. Now my .each function doesn't seem to call. I can log the array before the each, but once im past the .each nothing happens.

```
function grayDates() {
    var dateArray = ["2014-08-21", "2014-08-22", "2014-08-23", "2014-08-24", "2014-08-25", "2014-08-26", "2014-08-27", "2014-08-28", "2014-08-29", "2014-08-30", "2014-08-31", "2014-09-01", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-03"];
    console.log("this will be displayed in my console");
    $("td").each(function() {
        console.log("this will not be displayed");
        var date = $(this).data("date");
        if(dateArray.indexOf(date) > -1){
            $(this).addClass("vacation");
        }
    });
}
```

I load the libraries in the header like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

The function gets called after library and function defining, on doc ready. (event = php var filled with my events that are displayed)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    grayDates();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>',
        weekends: false,
        editable: true,
        lang: 'nl',
        events: [
            <?php echo $event;?>
            ]
    });
});
```

Not really at home in jQuery. Anyone that spots my mistake?

Comment: what does `$("td").length` tell?

Comment: When are you calling this function?  Is it possible you are loading the table cells via AJAX?  Is the page being loaded after this function is called?

Comment: If the `each` function doesn't run, there are no `<td>` elements, it's that simple, it's the only solution.

Comment: Please learn how to step through your code before posting questions here.

Comment: @Mritunjay TypeError: $(...).length is not a function

Comment: Have you tried moving `grayDates` below `fullCalendar`?

Comment: what does the html structure of the page look like? or better yet, could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Grinn Yes i have. It's there now.
Please check out my live example: [link](http://test.tdmd.nl/~diek/reserveren/calendar.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>',
        weekends: false,
        editable: true,
        lang: 'nl',
        events: [
            <?php echo $event;?>
            ]
    });
    grayDates();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me one step further. I now have a new error **ReferenceError: current is not defined
var date = $(current).data("date");** So i need to rename my var

Comment: Yes, that should be `$(this).data("date")` as it was in your original post.

Comment: ...same for `$(current).addClass("vakantie");` which should be `$(this).addClass("vakantie");`

Comment: Did that. Now im in my 'each'. Thanks for the help.